# Can You Use a Metamagic Rod and a Scroll/Staff/Wand Together?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, spells

Are you allowed to use a Metamagic Rod (say Extend) with a spell cast from a scroll or other magical device?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, unless the GM rules otherwise of course.  "[The modifications made by these [metamagic] feats only apply to spells cast directly by the feat user. A spellcaster can't use a metamagic feat to alter a spell being cast from a wand, scroll, or other device.](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats)"

And metamagic rods just let you [act as if you have the feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rods/metamagic-rods) a couple times a day.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding has always been no.  A scroll is a spell which is already 99% "cast" and merely awaits the final word/gesture/etc to finish the casting.  A metamagic rod needs to be a part of the entire casting of the spell.

Answer (score 1):

Artificers can use them while creating the scrolls. It's best if you have a wizard or cleric cast the spells as artificers often can't do the higher level metamagic such as persistent.